# use the origin lemma to show that there exists a hyperbolic reflection that maps 2 perpendicular d-lines to 2 perpendicular diameters of $\mathscr D$

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

Use the Origin Lemma to show that, given two d-lines meeting at right
angles, there is a hyperbolic reflection mapping them to two perpendicular
diameters of $\mathscr D$.

my work:

case 1 : two d-lines are diameters, then the hyperbolic reflection in any of the d-lines would do

case 2: two d-lines are arcs

case 3: one of the d-lines is arc, the other one is diameter.

I am not sure how origin lemma is relating to this problem. Thank you for your response and any feedback are appreciated.

Origin Lemma:

Let A be a point of $\mathscr D$ other than the origin O. Then there exists a d-line l
such that hyperbolic reflection in l maps A to O.

Comment: What is a d-line?

Comment: @zoli Definition: A d-line is that part of a (Euclidean) generalized circle which meets $L$ at right angles which lies in $\mathscr D$